# okhttp retrofit2 synchronize request crash

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp

My app uses rxjav, retrofit2, okhttp. Today it crashed:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.okhttp.reflection.okhttp3.Request$.getTargetClass(Request$.java:29)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.okhttp.reflection.okhttp3.Interceptor$$Chain$.proceed(Interceptor$.java:50)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.okhttp.OkHttp3Interceptor.invoke(OkHttp3Interceptor.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy0.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at net.luoo.LuooFM.http.OkHttpManager.lambda$initOkHttp3V3$0$OkHttpManager(OkHttpManager.java:152)
    at net.luoo.LuooFM.http.OkHttpManager$$Lambda$0.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
```

OkHttpManager.java:152 is

```
return chain.proceed(builder.url(request.url()).build());
```

this is the request:

```
@GET("/musics/songs/{id}")
Call<Song> getSong(@Path("id") long id);
```

if i use `Observable<Song> getSong(@Path("id") long songId);`,it work fine

Comment: Maybe the package of the Call method is not the Retrofit one?

Comment: is Android Studio's bug,i disable the profiler,it word fine

Comment: bug still there despite the fact it marked as fixed  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62435342